# Combine a List of lists into one list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

So for example I have this List : `L`
 `((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) ((d 4) (e 5) (f 6))`
how can I turn that into 
`((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5) (f 6))`

A list containing two lists that I need to make one list containing lists.

I know if I car L I get the front half `((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))` and if I `cdr` `L` I get the back half
`(((d 4) (e 5) (f 6)))` but I cant figure out how to turn it into the form 
`((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5) (f 6))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "combining" two lists (no matter their contents), use [`append`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._append%29%29). And for accessing the first and second elements of a list use `(car x)` and `(cadr x)` - which is shorthand for `(car (cdr x))`. For example:

```
(define lst '(((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) ((d 4) (e 5) (f 6))))

(append (car lst) (cadr lst))
=> '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5) (f 6))
```

For a more general solution that works with an arbitrary number of sublists, refer to @uselpa's fine answer using [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29). Or if you're using Racket, [`append*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append*%29%29) will also work for multiple sublists:

```
(define lst '(((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) ((d 4) (e 5) (f 6)) ((g 7) (h 8) (i 9))))

(append* lst)
=> '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5) (f 6) (g 7) (h 8) (i 9))
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for the quick reply! I'll mark as answer when it lets me.

Comment: @Crowlands great! it was my pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

To complement Oscar's answer, `(apply append ...)` works for any number of sublists:

```
(define L '(((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
            ((d 4) (e 5) (f 6))))
(apply append L)
=> '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5) (f 6))
```

and

```
(define G '(((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
            ((d 4) (e 5) (f 6))
            ((g 7) (h 8) (i 9))))
(apply append G)
=> '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5) (f 6) (g 7) (h 8) (i 9))
```

Comment: so `apply` just combines the first level of lists?

Comment: `apply append` does. `(apply append (L1 L2 L3 ...))` is the same as `(append L1 L2 L3 ...)`, so `apply` strips off one level of parentheses. It works with other procedures too.

Comment: @Crowlands or if you happen to be using Racket, `append*` will also work for multiple sublists ;)

Comment: You guys are great haha I wasn't expecting such a quick reply. Let alone to learn more then I asked. I'll upvote you as soon as I reach 15 feedback. Thanks again! @ÓscarLópez and uselpa

Comment: BTW, `apply` works for a limited number of arguments only. Folding is the recommended way to go, in this case for example (in Racket): `(foldl (lambda (e r) (append r e)) null H)`

Comment: @uselpa that's an issue in other Lisp interpreters, but not in Racket ;) see [here](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2010-August/041230.html). Now you can `apply` to your heart's content